# Express passed req.body.variable is empty in body of SOAP API call

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, express, soap

I create DPD Parcel label via the DPD Webservice SOAP API ( https://esolutions.dpd.com/dokumente/ShipmentService_V4_4.pdf https://esolutions.dpd.com/entwickler/dpdwebservices/dokumentationen.aspx). For this I have a route /dpdlabel where I receive json data for the label.
Like {"SNAME1":"My Company Name Ltd"}.
For the parcels label I need to have the **senders** name the corresponding variable is SNAME1.

When I receive an empty SNAME1-variable I want to have a default / fallback value for SNAME1.
So I wrote a ternary `const sname1 = Object.keys(req.body.SNAME1).length !== 0 ? req.body.SNAME1 : "My Company Ltd";`
When I console.log this it seems to be correct. But the API gives me a error back "...name is empty?...".

**Here is the error log:**

```
> Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (/Users/myname/Documents/dev/dpd/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (/Users/myname/Documents/dev/dpd/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/Users/myname/Documents/dev/dpd/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:388:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1336:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  config: {
    url: 'https://public-ws.dpd.com/services/ShipmentService/V4_4/?wsd',
    method: 'post',
    data: '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://dpd.com/common/service/types/Authentication/2.0" xmlns:ns1="http://dpd.com/common/service/types/ShipmentService/4.4" encoding="ISO8859-1">\n' +
      '    <soapenv:Header>\n' +
      '      <ns:authentication>\n' +
      '        <delisId>MYVALIDDELISID</delisId>\n' +
      '        <authToken>MYVALIDAUTHTOKEN</authToken>\n' +
      '        <messageLanguage>de_DE</messageLanguage>\n' +
      '      </ns:authentication>\n' +
      '    </soapenv:Header>\n' +
      '    <soapenv:Body>\n' +
      '    <ns1:storeOrders>\n' +
      '    <printOptions>\n' +
      '      <printOption>\n' +
      '        <outputFormat>PDF</outputFormat>\n' +
      '        <paperFormat>A6</paperFormat>\n' +
      '      </printOption>\n' +
      '    </printOptions>\n' +
      '    <order>\n' +
      '    <generalShipmentData>\n' +
      '      <sendingDepot>234</sendingDepot>\n' +
      '      <product>CL</product>\n' +
      '      <mpsCompleteDelivery>0</mpsCompleteDelivery>\n' +
      '      <sender>\n' +
      '        <name1>My Company Ltd</name1>\n' +
      '        <name2>-</name2>\n' +
      '        <street>straße 2</street>\n' +
      '        <country>DE</country>\n' +
      '        <zipCode>71272</zipCode>\n' +
      '        <city>Renningen</city>\n' +
      '        <customerNumber>12345679</customerNumber>\n' +
      '      </sender>\n' +
      '      <recipient>\n' +
      '        <name1>Supercompany</name1>\n' +
      '        <name2>Arthur Dent</name2>\n' +
      '        <street>Brückenstraße 35-37</street>\n' +
      '        <state>BW</state>\n' +
      '        <country>DE</country>\n' +
      '        <zipCode>47574</zipCode>\n' +
      '        <city>Goch</city>\n' +
      '        <contact>Superman</contact>\n' +
      '      </recipient>\n' +
      '    </generalShipmentData>\n' +
      '    <parcels>\n' +
      '        <customerReferenceNumber1>21-10900-1</customerReferenceNumber1>\n' +
      '      <customerReferenceNumber2></customerReferenceNumber2>\n' +
      '      <customerReferenceNumber3></customerReferenceNumber3>\n' +
      '      <customerReferenceNumber4></customerReferenceNumber4>\n' +
      '        <weight>500</weight>\n' +
      '        </parcels>\n' +
      '        <parcels>\n' +
      '        <customerReferenceNumber1>21-10900-1</customerReferenceNumber1>\n' +
      '      <customerReferenceNumber2></customerReferenceNumber2>\n' +
      '      <customerReferenceNumber3></customerReferenceNumber3>\n' +
      '      <customerReferenceNumber4></customerReferenceNumber4>\n' +
      '        <weight>500</weight>\n' +
      '        </parcels>\n' +
      '        \n' +
      '    <productAndServiceData>\n' +
      '    <orderType>consignment</orderType>\n' +
      '    </productAndServiceData>\n' +
      '    </order>\n' +
      '    </ns1:storeOrders>\n' +
      '    </soapenv:Body>\n' +
      '   </soapenv:Envelope>',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.1',
      'Content-Length': 2270
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus]
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'public-ws.dpd.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'public-ws.dpd.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 44,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: 'POST /services/ShipmentService/V4_4/?wsd HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\n' +
      'Content-Length: 2270\r\n' +
      'Host: public-ws.dpd.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/services/ShipmentService/V4_4/?wsd',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 500,
      statusMessage: 'Internal Server Error',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: true,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://public-ws.dpd.com/services/ShipmentService/V4_4/?wsd',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'public-ws.dpd.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 2270,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://public-ws.dpd.com/services/ShipmentService/V4_4/?wsd',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 500,
    statusText: 'Internal Server Error',
    headers: {
      date: 'Tue, 19 Oct 2021 07:22:43 GMT',
      server: 'Jetty(6.1.x)',
      'content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
      vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
      connection: 'close',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked'
    },
    config: {
      url: 'https://public-ws.dpd.com/services/ShipmentService/V4_4/?wsd',
      method: 'post',
      data: '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://dpd.com/common/service/types/Authentication/2.0" xmlns:ns1="http://dpd.com/common/service/types/ShipmentService/4.4" encoding="ISO8859-1">\n' +
        '    <soapenv:Header>\n' +
        '      <ns:authentication>\n' +
        '        <delisId>MYVALIDDELISID</delisId>\n' +
        '        <authToken>MYVALIDAUTHCODE</authToken>\n' +
        '        <messageLanguage>de_DE</messageLanguage>\n' +
        '      </ns:authentication>\n' +
        '    </soapenv:Header>\n' +
        '    <soapenv:Body>\n' +
        '    <ns1:storeOrders>\n' +
        '    <printOptions>\n' +
        '      <printOption>\n' +
        '        <outputFormat>PDF</outputFormat>\n' +
        '        <paperFormat>A6</paperFormat>\n' +
        '      </printOption>\n' +
        '    </printOptions>\n' +
        '    <order>\n' +
        '    <generalShipmentData>\n' +
        '      <sendingDepot>234</sendingDepot>\n' +
        '      <product>CL</product>\n' +
        '      <mpsCompleteDelivery>0</mpsCompleteDelivery>\n' +
        '      <sender>\n' +
        '        <name1>My Company Ltd</name1>\n' +
        '        <name2>-</name2>\n' +
        '        <street>straße 2</street>\n' +
        '        <country>DE</country>\n' +
        '        <zipCode>71272</zipCode>\n' +
        '        <city>Renningen</city>\n' +
        '        <customerNumber>12345679</customerNumber>\n' +
        '      </sender>\n' +
        '      <recipient>\n' +
        '        <name1>Supercompany</name1>\n' +
        '        <name2>Arthur Dent</name2>\n' +
        '        <street>Brückenstraße 35-37</street>\n' +
        '        <state>BW</state>\n' +
        '        <country>DE</country>\n' +
        '        <zipCode>47574</zipCode>\n' +
        '        <city>Goch</city>\n' +
        '        <contact>Superman</contact>\n' +
        '      </recipient>\n' +
        '    </generalShipmentData>\n' +
        '    <parcels>\n' +
        '        <customerReferenceNumber1>21-10900-1</customerReferenceNumber1>\n' +
        '      <customerReferenceNumber2></customerReferenceNumber2>\n' +
        '      <customerReferenceNumber3></customerReferenceNumber3>\n' +
        '      <customerReferenceNumber4></customerReferenceNumber4>\n' +
        '        <weight>500</weight>\n' +
        '        </parcels>\n' +
        '        <parcels>\n' +
        '        <customerReferenceNumber1>21-10900-1</customerReferenceNumber1>\n' +
        '      <customerReferenceNumber2></customerReferenceNumber2>\n' +
        '      <customerReferenceNumber3></customerReferenceNumber3>\n' +
        '      <customerReferenceNumber4></customerReferenceNumber4>\n' +
        '        <weight>500</weight>\n' +
        '        </parcels>\n' +
        '        \n' +
        '    <productAndServiceData>\n' +
        '    <orderType>consignment</orderType>\n' +
        '    </productAndServiceData>\n' +
        '    </order>\n' +
        '    </ns1:storeOrders>\n' +
        '    </soapenv:Body>\n' +
        '   </soapenv:Envelope>',
      headers: [Object],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus]
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'POST /services/ShipmentService/V4_4/?wsd HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.21.1\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 2270\r\n' +
        'Host: public-ws.dpd.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/services/ShipmentService/V4_4/?wsd',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'public-ws.dpd.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    data: `<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>cvc-length-valid: Value '172' with length = '3' is not facet-valid with respect to length '4' for type '#AnonType_sendingDepotgeneralShipmentData'.</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>`
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
}
```

Also in the axios error the send xml contains the correct sname1 value.
What am I doing wrong?

**Here is the Code:**

```
   //==========================================
        //                Imports
        //==========================================
        require('dotenv').config();
        const express = require('express');
        const axios = require('axios');
        require('dotenv').config();
        const xmlParser = require('fast-xml-parser');
        var he = require('he');
        const app = express();
        //==========================================
        
        
        //==========================================
        //           APP CONFIG & SETTINGS
        //==========================================
        app.use(express.json());
        app.use(express.static("public"));
        app.use(express.urlencoded({
          extended: true
        }));
        
        //==========================================
        //                 ROUTING
        //==========================================
        app.post('/dpdlabel',(req,res)=>{
               const depotId = req.body.DEPOTID;
    const shipmenttype = req.body.SHIPMENTTYPE;
    const rname1 = req.body.RNAME1;
    const rname2 = req.body.RNAME2;
    const rstreet = req.body.RSTREET;
    const rpostal = req.body.RPOSTAL;
    const rcity = req.body.RCITY;
    const rcountry = req.body.RCOUNTRY;
    const rcontact = req.body.RCONTACT;
    const raddressref = req.body.RADDRESSREF;
    const parcelref1 = req.body.PARCELREF1;
    const parcelref2 = req.body.PARCELREF2;
    const parcelref3 = req.body.PARCELREF3;
    const parcelref4 = req.body.PARCELREF4;
    const weight = req.body.WEIGHT;
    const rstate = req.body.RSTATE;
    const parcelcount = req.body.PARCELCOUNT;
    const sname1 = Object.keys(req.body.SNAME1).length !== 0 ? req.body.SNAME1 : "My Company Ltd";
    const sname2 = req.body.SNAME2;
    const sstreet = req.body.SSTREET;
    const shouseno = req.body.SHOUSENO;
    const scountry = req.body.SCOUNTRY;
    const spostal = req.body.SPOSTAL;
    const scity = req.body.SCITY;
    const scontact = req.body.SCONTACT;
    const saddressinfo = req.body.SADDRESSINFO;
        
            var data = `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"\n xmlns:ns="http://dpd.com/common/service/types/LoginService/2.0">\n <soapenv:Header/>\n <soapenv:Body>\n <ns:getAuth>\n <delisId>${process.env.DELISID}</delisId>\n <password>${process.env.DPDSECRET}</password>\n <messageLanguage>de_DE</messageLanguage>\n </ns:getAuth>\n </soapenv:Body>\n<soapenv:Envelope>`;
        
        var config = {
          method: 'post',
          url: 'https://public-ws.dpd.com/services/LoginService/V2_0/?wsd',
          headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/soap+xml'
          },
          data : data
        };
        
        axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            const authRes = JSON.stringify(response.data);
            
            var options = {
                attributeNamePrefix : "@_",
                attrNodeName: false, //default is 'false'
                textNodeName : "#text",
                ignoreAttributes : false,
                ignoreNameSpace : false,
                allowBooleanAttributes : false,
                parseNodeValue : true,
                parseAttributeValue : false,
                trimValues: true,
                cdataTagName: "__cdata", //default is 'false'
                cdataPositionChar: "\\c",
                parseTrueNumberOnly: false,
                arrayMode: false, //"strict"
                attrValueProcessor: (val, attrName) => he.decode(val, {isAttributeValue: true}),//default is a=>a
                tagValueProcessor : (val, tagName) => he.decode(val), //default is a=>a
                stopNodes: ["parse-me-as-string"]
            };
            
            var jsonObj = xmlParser.parse(response.data,options);
            var tObj = xmlParser.getTraversalObj(response.data,options);
            var jsonObj = xmlParser.convertToJson(tObj,options);

            const delisId = jsonObj['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['ns2:getAuthResponse']['return']['delisId'];
            const authToken = jsonObj['soap:Envelope']['soap:Body']['ns2:getAuthResponse']['return']['authToken'];
            // LABEL PDF ANFORDERN
            function generateParcels( amount, weight ) {
              let parcelString = "";
              for ( i=1; i<=amount; i++ ){
                parcelString += `<parcels>
                <customerReferenceNumber1>${parcelref1}</customerReferenceNumber1>
              <customerReferenceNumber2>${parcelref2}</customerReferenceNumber2>
              <customerReferenceNumber3>${parcelref3}</customerReferenceNumber3>
              <customerReferenceNumber4>${parcelref4}</customerReferenceNumber4>
                <weight>${weight}</weight>
                </parcels>
                `
              }
              return parcelString
            };
            const generatedParcels = generateParcels( parcelcount, weight );
            const contact = rcontact ? `<contact>${rcontact}</contact>` : "";
            const name2 = rname2 ? `<name2>${rname2}</name2>` : "";
            var data = `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://dpd.com/common/service/types/Authentication/2.0" xmlns:ns1="http://dpd.com/common/service/types/ShipmentService/4.4" encoding="ISO8859-1">
            <soapenv:Header>
              <ns:authentication>
                <delisId>${delisId}</delisId>
                <authToken>${authToken}</authToken>
                <messageLanguage>de_DE</messageLanguage>
              </ns:authentication>
            </soapenv:Header>
            <soapenv:Body>
            <ns1:storeOrders>
            <printOptions>
              <printOption>
                <outputFormat>PDF</outputFormat>
                <paperFormat>A6</paperFormat>
              </printOption>
            </printOptions>
            <order>
            <generalShipmentData>
              <sendingDepot>${depotId}</sendingDepot>
              <product>${shipmenttype}</product>
              <mpsCompleteDelivery>0</mpsCompleteDelivery>
              <sender>
                <name1>${sname1}</name1>
                <name2>${sname2}</name2>
                <street>${sstreet}</street>
                <country>${scountry}</country>
                <zipCode>${spostal}</zipCode>
                <city>${scity}</city>
                <customerNumber>12345679</customerNumber>
              </sender>
              <recipient>
                <name1>${rname1}</name1>
                ${name2}
                <street>${rstreet}</street>
                <state>${rstate}</state>
                <country>${rcountry}</country>
                <zipCode>${rpostal}</zipCode>
                <city>${rcity}</city>
                ${contact}
              </recipient>
            </generalShipmentData>
            ${generatedParcels}
            <productAndServiceData>
            <orderType>consignment</orderType>
            </productAndServiceData>
            </order>
            </ns1:storeOrders>
            </soapenv:Body>
           </soapenv:Envelope>`;
        
            var config = {
                method: 'post',
                url: 'https://public-ws.dpd.com/services/ShipmentService/V4_4/?wsd',
                headers: { 
                  'Content-Type': "application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8"
                },
                data : data
              };
              
              axios(config)
              .then(function (response) {
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                var options = {
                  attributeNamePrefix : "@_",
                  attrNodeName: false, //default is 'false'
                  textNodeName : "#text",
                  ignoreAttributes : false,
                  ignoreNameSpace : false,
                  allowBooleanAttributes : false,
                  parseNodeValue : true,
                  parseAttributeValue : false,
                  trimValues: true,
                  cdataTagName: "__cdata", //default is 'false'
                  cdataPositionChar: "\\c",
                  parseTrueNumberOnly: false,
                  arrayMode: false, //"strict"
                  attrValueProcessor: (val, attrName) => he.decode(val, {isAttributeValue: true}),//default is a=>a
                  tagValueProcessor : (val, tagName) => he.decode(val), //default is a=>a
                  stopNodes: ["parse-me-as-string"]
              };
              var jsonObj = xmlParser.parse(response.data,options);
                  var tObj = xmlParser.getTraversalObj(response.data,options);
                  var jsonObj = xmlParser.convertToJson(tObj,options);
                  res.json(jsonObj).end;
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
              // END OF DPD LABEL
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
          res.send('500');
        });
        })
        //==========================================
        
        
        //==========================================
        //             SERVER LISTENER
        //==========================================
        
        const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
            console.log("Server started on port "+listener.address().port);
          });
        //==========================================
```

Comment: why not just do `const sname1 = req.body.SNAME1 || "My Company Ltd";`, else can you just check if you receive sname1 correctly ?

Comment: @Kidas Will use this shorter syntax of you thx. atm I am sending the JSON via postman. I receive it yes its typeof is string. Event in the error log you can see that the data send to the api contains the correct fallback value under "<sender><name1>". When I fill SNAME1 it works but when I send an empty string in my postman call I get the error 500.

Comment: `<faultstring>cvc-length-valid: Value '172' with length = '3' is not facet-valid with respect to length '4' for type '#AnonType_sendingDepotgeneralShipmentData'.</faultstring>`, can you try to replace the sendingDepot value with 0234 instead of 234. check the documentation here page 16 https://esolutions.dpd.com/dokumente/ShipmentService_V3_2.pdf

Comment: @Kidas The depot ID in my post is fake. In my code its correct and starts with a 0. ^^

Comment: oh gosh I found it...‍♂️  The Fallback value had and special char "&" that crashed the code. I thought having Content-Type header with the charset of utf8 and defining the encoding of the xml as ISO8859-1  would solve those issues with german special characters.
I am sorry for wasting your time...